# Prove the following lemma

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> If $f$ is differentiable at $X_o$, then $f(X)-f(X_o)= (d_{x_o} f)(X-X_o)+ E(X)|X-X_o|$, where E is defined in the neighborhood of $X_o$ and $\lim_{X\to X_o}$ $E(X)=E(X_o)=0$

I don't know how to go about this proof. The hint given was that only $E$ needed to be proven continuous. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Define $e(x) = \begin{cases} 0,& x=x_0 \\
{1 \over \|x-x_0\|} (f(x)-f(x_0)-Df(x_0)(x-x_0)), & x\neq x_0
\end{cases}$.

Showing $e$ is continuous at $x_0$ is a matter of applying the
definition of differentiability of $f$ at $x_0$.

Let $\epsilon>0$, then there exists some $\delta>0$ such that if
$|h\|< \delta$ then $\|f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-Df(x_0)(h)\| \le \epsilon \|h\|$.

If we choose $x \in B(x_0,\delta)\setminus \{x_0\}$, and let $h=x-x_0$, then
 $\|e(x)\| < \epsilon$, and so $e$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: But this is a multivariable equation so how does one go about the solution then?

Comment: I don't understand your question? The answer above works for any normed space, which includes $\mathbb{R}^n$.